# Microsoft ad b2c issue: policy is missing

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory

I made a chat bot which I want to authorize user using Azure ad b2c using OIDCStrategy. In the console, it always logs `authentication failed due to: In collectInfoFromReq: policy is missing`. The policy has been set in Azure. And I can't find somewhere to declare the policy in the code. Here is my server:

```
server.get('/login',
     passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect',
     {
          failureRedirect:'/fail'
     }),
     function(req,res,next){
         console.log('Login was called');
         res.redirect('/',next); 
     }
)

server.post('/api/auth', passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect'));
```

And connection to the azure ad b2c:

```
passport.use(new OIDCStrategy({
    redirectUrl:'http://localhost:3978/api/auth',
    allowHttpForRedirectUrl:true,
    clientID:'5fe844d7-e4d1-4c4c-ba70-078297b00abc',
    clientSecret:'?aTvTEbwcNfUF2,^',
    identityMetadata: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/nuffieldbot.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration', 
    skipUserProfile: true,
    responseType: 'code',
    responseMode: 'form_post',
    isB2C:true,
    scope:['email','profile','offline_access','https://outlook.office.com/mail/read'],
    loggingLevel:'info',
    tenantName:'nuffieldbot.onmicrosoft.com',
    passReqToCallback:true
},function(req, iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, done){
   log.info('Example:Email address we received was:', profile.email);
   process.nextTick(function(){
       findByEmail(profile.email,function(err,user){
           if (err) {
               return done(err);
           }
           if (!user){
               users.push(profile);
               return done(null, profile);
           }
           return done(null, user);
       })
   })
  }

));
```

Where can I declare this policy in my code?

Answer (score 1):

For B2C, we must have policy , if you have not set policy name in query string of request , it will throw error : `In collectInfoFromReq: policy is missing` . Please refer to [source code](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad/blob/dev/lib/oidcstrategy.js#L747) of oidcstrategy.js :

```
 // for B2C, we must have policy
  if (self._options.isB2C && !params.policy)
    return next(new Error('In collectInfoFromReq: policy is missing'));
```

You must set policy in request :

```
 <a href="/login/?p=B2C_1_sign">Sign In</a>
```

You could also refer to code sample : [Azure Active Directory OIDC Web Sample](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-NodeJS)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually i have read this sample before. In my bot dialog, i have a button which link to "/login?p=B2C_1_signin". Before that, i can't call the sign in page. Now the case is i can call the sign in page and use the account i create but the passport still return unauthorized due to that error. So i wonder that is there somewhere else i can declare the policy.

Comment: @ZhenningLou ,the same error you got after adding policy in query string  ?

Comment: Yeah, i create the a const  link = 'http://localhost:3978/login?p=B2C_1_signin'  and i still got the error.

Comment: Also, if i go to Azure portal directly run the policy, the localhost server will still throw this error and authenticate is failed. @Nan Yu

Comment: That seems server side not get the policy name from request , could you please share your code sample or provide details to help us reproduce this problem ?

Comment: I solve the problem by adding restify.queryParser(). @Nan Yu

Comment: which is funny because we define policyName in the passport strategy options. so you would expect the library to be able to handle that. Putting the policy name to both backend and frontend doesn't make sense, so I'll probably use a nodejs middleware to add the `p` query param.